# How to make Ansible ignore the user's environment?

Tags: environment-variables, ansible

Ansible deployments (with `ansible-playbook`) take the current environment settings into account.

Does Ansible have a configuration option to disable that and specify the environment in the configuration?

We want deployments to be reproducible.

Answer (score 0):

> Q: *"Does Ansible have a configuration option to disable that and specify the environment in the configuration?"*

A: No. There is no such option. Make the deployment reproducible by reproducing the environment. [Environment variables have higher precedence](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html#configuration-settings).